# How to resend GET request with requests library until I get desired response? (Python)

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I work at a webproject were I need to 1) create a user 2) log in with the user credentials. The problem is there's an unspecified amount of time before the user gets added to the database, so I need to wait for that amount of time.

I want to create an explicit wait that would send GET requests every n seconds until the response contains the added user credentials.

```
from time import sleep
from requests import Session

session = Session()

url = 'app_url_with_user_list_endpoint'

resp = session.get(url=url)
while resp.json()[-1]["email"] != "new_use@samplemail.fake":
     sleep(0.5)
     resp = session.get(url=url)
```

Here, I tried to update the *resp* until it contains the new user email. But, I just created an infitine loop.

So, how do I wait for the response to hold the desired email? Optional: how do I specify max number of retries?

Comment: >{So, how do I wait for the response to hold the desired email?} There's really no way to do it without just making requests in a loop. If the time is really unspecified, you might want to do exponential backoff (first wait for 1s, then for 2s, then for 4s etc.).  
>{how do I specify max number of retries?} You can use a `for` loop over a `range` with `break`

Comment: @decorator-factory  Sounds like a soulution. Could you please add an example with the code I provided?

Comment: Sounds like `shredEngineer` already did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work? (Limited to 10 tries, which here amounts to a timeout of 5 seconds.)

```
from time import sleep
from requests import Session

session = Session()

url = 'app_url_with_user_list_endpoint'
match = "new_use@samplemail.fake"

success = False
for _ in range(10):
    resp = session.get(url=url)
    if resp.json()[-1]["email"] == match:
        success = True
        break
    sleep(0.5)

if success:
    print("Success: User was added")
else:
    print("Timeout: Failed to add user")
```